# Tomcat redirect to data file

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, redirect

I'm trying to use Tomcat 6 on an apache webserver to download data files (ascii), edit them, and then redirect users to a local copy of the edited version. My problem is that I can't seem to get permissions/configurations right.

I'm trying to move the files to `${catalina.base}/temp/stuff.txt`

and redirect users to `http://address.com:8080/temp/stuff.txt`

But fiddling around with the permissions and making Contexts hasn't shown any success. Instead I get:

```
type: Status report

message: /temp/stuff.txt

description: The requested resource (/temp/stuff.txt) is not available.
```

How would you go about doing this?

I'm fairly new with tomcat so all help and advice on what to read up on are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to make sure that the requested file does really exist in the indicated path. You can do this by looking the folder. Also, you can try to access other files in that folder.

Second, you need to check the permission/ownership (using `ls -l`) of the folder and files in it. Tomcat user (such as `tomcat`) should have read permissions to be able access the requested file.

Comment: The directory `${catalina.base}/temp/` has 755 permissions and the file inside of it (which exists) has 664 permissions, but even 777 permissions don't make it work. I've tried moving them to `${catalina.base}/webapps/ROOT/temp`, but that doesn't help either